# What material(s) to seal exterior water pipe opening in masonry?

Tags: concrete, sealing, caulking

I have an opening for an exterior water pipe/hose bib as shown:

[image]

The opening is about 2.5" wide and I don't have direct access to the back side. What material(s) should I use to seal the opening? I thought about just building a "wall" of caulk around the pipe (and then caulking the escutcheon over it), but will caulk hold the shape necessary to fill the entire space around the pipe, or will it just settle into a blob at the bottom?

Should I use some type of foam product instead? The ones I have found say they will break down in UV light, which would be an issue here.

Note that the pipe is not centered in the opening so even with the escutcheon over the opening there will still be a gap between it and the masonry that needs to be sealed:

[image]

When I moved in there was no escutcheon covering the opening and the hole was stuffed with rocks and a couple lumps of caulk. I figured there must be a better way to seal this.

Comment: How do you feel about using mortar/concrete?

Comment: @JPhi1618 I don't have any experience with that and am not sure how well it would come out if I tried.

Answer (score 1):

How about indirect access to the backside just to see if there needs to be a space around the pipe. Pipes are usually just inserted through holes drilled in brick or block so to support the pipe from kinking,you could pack the hole with Quikrete or some other concrete patch. Just make sure you check inside the hole to make sure the hose bib isn't a silcock that would need a larger opening to remove it if needed. You wouldn't even need the escutcheon and try to form in the existing mortar lines.

Comment: The backside of the pipe is in the wall between two adjacent garages of two separate units and I don't have any way of accessing it. How would you recommend sealing the opening from the front?

Comment: Just get some Quikrete, concrete patch or mortar. Mix it thick and pack it in the hole. You don't need to fill the entire hole, just 1" or so. What's inside that hole?

Comment: Nothing - the pipe just goes a few inches through an opening as wide as the one shown in the picture, and then goes into a smaller hole in the back of the masonry. Would an expanding foam work just as well as concrete or mortar in this case?

Comment: @user2150989  Problem is the pipe can wobble back and forth putting a lot of stress on the pipe where it goes through the smaller hole, possibly scoring or kinking the pipe.